# How can we use LINQ to sort a list where some predefined values should appear first?

Tags: c#, linq

Similar to [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392542/sort-a-list-with-known-values-before-unknown-values) I want to sort a `List<T>` where a known set of values should come first (if present), after which we use the default order - e.g. `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. Efficient code is desirable, but I'm more interested in a clever `LINQ` expression.

### Sample data

```
Known:    e c
Input:    c b e d a
Output:   e c a b d

Known:    e c
Input:    b a c e c
Output:   e c c a b

Known:    e c
Input:    b d f a
Output:   a b d f
```

### Wanted API

Some minor tweaks might be necessary. Note the `keySelector`, allowing us to choose a property as sorting target.

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> input,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    {
        // TODO: Clever LINQ implementation here!
        yield break;
    }
}
```

### Sample program

```cs
class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(string name) => Name = name;
        public string Name { get; }
        public override string ToString() => Name;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] knownValues = { "e", "c" }; // We can assume that these values are unique!
        var (a, b, c, d, e) = (new Foo("a"), new Foo("b"), new Foo("c"), new Foo("d"), new Foo("e"));
        
        var input = new List<Foo> { c, b, e, d, a };
        var expected = new List<Foo> { e, c, a, b, d };
        var actual = input.Sort(t => t.Name, knownValues).ToList();
        
        Console.WriteLine(expected.SequenceEqual(actual) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL");
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + string.Join(", ", expected));
        Console.WriteLine("Actual:   " + string.Join(", ", actual));
    }
}
```

Comment: `var known = input.Where(ts => knownValues.Any(k => k.Equals(keySelector(ts)))).OrderBy(ts => Array.IndexOf(knownValues, keySelector(ts))); return known.Union(input.Except(known).OrderBy(ts => keySelector(ts)));`

Comment: What is the expected output for `Known: e c e` and `Input: a b c d e e`? Is it `e c e a b d` or `e e c a b d`, or something else?

Comment: I did specify that we can assume `known` values are unique. Thus, `Known: e c` and `Input: a b c d e e` should result in the _latter_; `Output: e e c a b d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately .Net doesn't have an `IndexOf` that returns one past the upper bound when the element isn't found, but you can write one:

```
public static class ArrayExt {
    public static int PastIndexOf<T>(this T[] array, T val) {
        var index = array.IndexOf(val);
        return index == -1 ? array.Length : index;
    }
}
```

NOTE: This feels unfortunate to me, since the framework has special code to handle the `-1` return and now we are adding special code on top of it to undo that, but writing our own implementation would probably be slower then `Array.IndexOf` which has special optimizations.

With this extension method, your method is simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    => input.OrderBy(i => knownValues.PastIndexOf(keySelector(i))).ThenBy(i => keySelector(i));
```

Alternatively, you can use a generic extension method to catch the concept of testing and replacing a value:

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static T ElseIf<T>(this T a, Func<T,bool> testFn, T b) => testFn(a) ? b : a;
}
```

And then write your method using this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    => input.OrderBy(i => knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(i)).ElseIf(n => n == -1, knownValues.Length+1)).ThenBy(i => keySelector(i));
```

NOTE: Of course, these extension methods makeup for C#'s lack of a easy declaration expression where you could just use `?:`. These are generalizations of `??` that feel like could use a more succinct expression, but I don't know what it would be.

PS: You can have a declaration expression, it just hard to read:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    => input.OrderBy(i => (knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(i)) is var v) && v >= 0 ? v : knownValues.Length+1).ThenBy(i => keySelector(i));
```

PPS: Or using C# 9 extended pattern matching:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    => input.OrderBy(i => knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(i)) is var v and >= 0 ? v : knownValues.Length+1).ThenBy(i => keySelector(i));
```

PPPS: As pointed out by @l33t, a `uint` cast of the return value of `IndexOf` will produce the proper ordering:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, TKey[] knownValues)
    => input.OrderBy(i => (uint)knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(i))).ThenBy(i => keySelector(i));
    // cast IndexOf return value to uint to move not found to the end
```

Comment: I think the idea of using a "past index" is the right solution. Perhaps add a "PPPS" with a `(uint)` cast variant? :)

Comment: @l33t I added it.

Comment: Nice answer, but the formatting of the code makes it difficult to read because of the horizontal scrolling needed. I guess it should look fine in a some ultrawide screen with 3840 horizontal pixels, but I don't have any to confirm it. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias my 2560 x 1600 screens says that it wouldn't help - stackoverflow sites aren't responsive to horizontal growth, as zoom will show you :( You can only see 90 characters horizontally, and that is far too few for C# in my book.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :

```
var actual = input
    .OrderByDescending(o => knownValues.Contains(o.Name))
    .ThenBy(o => knownValues.FindIndex(p => o.Name == p))
    .ThenBy(o => o.Name)
    .ToList();
```

`OrderByDescending` will split the list in two parts. The known values and the unknown values. The first `ThenBy` will order the known values in the same order than the `knownValues` array and the last `ThenBy` will order the unknown values.

Comment: Ok, so if we change `knownValues` to a `List<T>` and then use the `keySelector`, it will indeed work:

`input.OrderByDescending(o => knownValues.Contains(keySelector(o))).ThenBy(o => knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(o))).ThenBy(keySelector)`

So three sort operations in total. Can we improve it?

Comment: How about this? `input.OrderBy(o => (uint)knownValues.IndexOf(keySelector(o))).ThenBy(keySelector)`

Comment: @NetMage Just trying to be creative. Casting to `uint` should be equivalent to `PastIndexOf` of yours. No?

Comment: @l33t Yes, I think you are right... very good!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The easiest method is probably to use [.ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ThenBy__2_System_Linq_IOrderedEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__)

Example assumes the items are comparable and equatable for simplicity, and that input and knownvalues have the same type.

```
input.OrderBy(i => knownValues.Contains(i) )
      .ThenBy(i => i)
```